# Monotouch debugs for 5 seconds before iOS 4.2 kills the app

Tags: debugging, ipad, mono, timeout, xamarin.ios

I am testing on an iPad a Monotouch app. Running iOS 4.2

The iPad kills the app in debug mode as I step thru after 5 seconds. The iPad has a built in timer that kills apps if they fail to respond in 5 seconds. (like Android's ANR)

Is there a way to tell the iPad to not do that so that I can debug for more than 5 seconds?

Note: On the iPad the app is set to Debug Enabled under the iPad Settings tool. There is no timeout setting though it seems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you do not step the ViewDidLoad method or anything that gets called from within FinishedLaunching as there is a timeout for application until it as to start.

Rather create a separate thread you start upon starting your app that initializes, show some splash screen before it and once the init is done, hide the splashscreen.

This is the recommended approach.

The reason is, that apps start in a timely fashion and user does not need to wait for app to start. However makes it harder to debug the init routine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you have any resources with some sample code on this approach?